# Get Percentage Laravel in Localhost Works, but Live server not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, percentage

iam try get percentage, in my localhost working, but on my server still nor working, this in my code

```
@php
  $data_course = \App\Course::where('id', $course->course_id)->first();

   $total_lesson = \App\Lesson::where('course_id', $course->id)->count();

   $total_lesson_completed = \App\LessonCompleted::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('course_id', $course->id)->count();

    if ($total_lesson_completed != 0) {
              $percent = round(($total_lesson_completed / $total_lesson) * 100);
    }else{
              $percent = 0;
     }

    @endphp
```

Comment: Does any error occur? what is result print in the blade?

Comment: in the live server, always return 0 value

Comment: You can check with `dd($total_lesson)` and `dd($total_lesson_completed)` return?

Comment: What is the value of `$total_lesson_completed` count on live server?

Comment: in the live server, data already sir

Comment: @FikaRidaulMaulayya Make sure you must have $total_lesson > 0 which is used to divide the value of $total_lesson_completed. If the $total_lesson_completed <= 0 then it will always return 0 as a result.

Comment: @FikaRidaulMaulayya That is why i told him what is the result of  `dd($total_lesson)` and `dd($total_lesson_completed)`